# Django App Log level info not getting write into file

Tags: python, django

I have added below setting in Django for Info level log.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(LOGGING=settings.LOGGING)

LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'level': logging.INFO,
        'filename': '/logs/django/api.log',
        'interval': 1,
        'when': 'midnight',
        'encoding': 'utf8'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': logging.INFO,
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
}
```

If I change this level to Debug then it works properly but when I change it to INFO Level then the log will not be written into the file. Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you sure you application have log at the INFO Level or higher ? Maybe you just log at the DEBUG level ?

Comment: @Thom there is default INFO level log. I removed this statement from setting. `logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'test.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
        'request_handler': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'django_request.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['request_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        },
    }
}
```

In your code:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info("My name is Info")
```

Sample output:

```
2017-05-25 04:56:38,912 [INFO] api.views: API - initiate_scan view, new object created. Uid: cf3822b261790186297d30e4f5b448b2
```

Comment: This is Debug level log. I want to write `INFO` level logs.

Comment: As per my edit: you can print it as logger.info right?

Comment: yes I changed only Log Level @ Abijith I think there is minor mistake done by me

Comment: As far as your question. If you want to write both debug and info level logs in same file then my answer suits the best. But if planning to write diff level in diff files then you have to write respective handlers with corresponding loggers in settings.py and specify the function calls accdly in your code!